# re.escape() equivalent in Julia?

Tags: regex, string, nlp, julia, escaping

I have a bunch of abbreviations I'd like to use in `RegEx` matches, but they contain lots of regex reserved characters (like `. ? $`).
In Python you're able to return an escaped (regex safe) string using `re.escape`. For example:

`re.escape("Are U.S. Pythons worth any $$$?")` will return `'Are\\ U\\.S\\.\\ Pythons\\ worth\\ any\\ \\$\\$\\$\\?'`

From my (little) experience with Julia so far, I can tell there's probably a much more straightforward way of doing this in Julia, by I couldn't find any previous answers on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia uses the PCRE2 library underneath, and uses its [regex-quoting syntax](https://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC5) to automatically escape special characters when you join a Regex with a normal String. For eg.

```
julia> r"\w+\s*" * raw"Are U.S. Pythons worth any $$$?"
r"(?:\w+\s*)\QAre U.S. Pythons worth any $$$?\E"
```

Here we've used a `raw` string to make sure that none of the characters are interpreted as special, including the `$`s.

If we needed interpolation, we can also use a normal String literal instead. In this case, the interpolation will be done, and *then* the quoting with `\Q ... \E`.

```
julia> snake = "Python"
"Python"

julia> r"\w+\s*" * "Are U.S. $snake worth any money?"
r"(?:\w+\s*)\QAre U.S. Python worth any money?\E"
```

So you can place the part of the regex you wish to be quoted in a normal String, and they'll be quoted automatically when you join them up with a Regex.

You can even do it directly within the regex yourself - `\Q` starts a region where none of the regex-special characters are interpreted as special, and `\E` ends that region. Everything within such a region is treated literally by the regex engine.

Comment: This is perfect. What a beautiful language!